# Windows 10 doesn't include all programs in search

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

When searching on Windows 10, by clicking the win-key and start typing, not all programs can be found.

E.g. I can find the VLC player by typing vlc.
If I type ditto, it doesn't find anything, even though the program is located next to VLC. There are several other programs than can't be found.

I try to right click the shortcuts and open file locations, thinking perhaps Windows won't find the shortcut if it's installed for all users or something else.

VLC have this path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\VideoLAN

Ditto have this path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Ditto

How can I make Windows find everything in the Start Menu folder?

Comment: use a better search tool like Everything.exe from voidtools.com  although if you search for Indexing options, this may offer more insight